# Undo Password Reset in salesforce

Tags: login

I have generated a password reset email for a user mistakenly, is there any way to undo this or call back the password reset email so that the user can login with his current password again. Right now he has received the password reset email but he does not wish to reset it and he is also unable to login with current password until he reset it with new one. any solution please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot undo an admin-initiated password reset process.

Source: [Reset your Salesforce login password without your security question answer](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385073&type=1)

> When a System Administrator or Salesforce Support triggers a password reset to your user, your old password will be invalidated immediately. This means you will no longer be able to log in with that password. You will need to finish resetting your password in order to successfully sign in.